# Having an unexpected output when reversing a string in C++

Tags: c++, string

I wrote a simple code to reverse a string but I get a strange output. For example, if I type "hello" I get at output " qlleh" and I sincerely don't know why.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int a = 0;
  char s[1024],r[1024];

cout<<"Enter a string:";
cin>>s;
    for(int i = char_traits<char>::length(s); i >= 0; i--){
                //if(isalpha(s[i]))
                r[a++] += s[i];
    }


    cout<<r;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `+=` in `r[a++] += s[i];`?  You should be doing a straight assignment which is `=`.

Comment: if I use a simple assignment it will replace one letter with another every time the loop iterates ...

Comment: What are you expecting that `+=` to do, exactly?

Comment: (Note that it's the `+=` that NathanOliver is asking you about, not the `++`.)

Comment: What @NathanOliver said, plus: start your loop with `i = len(s) - 1` otherwise `r` will start with `\0` and won't be printed and after the loop set `r[a]='\0'`, cf. [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a21ba8a61ac2864d)

Comment: @JONNICAREYN You say "assignment it will replace one letter with another every time the loop iterates" as though it were a bad thing. I would think that's exactly what you want.

Comment: @nils , thanks, now I understand what was the problem .

Comment: Next time you could actually use [`string`s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a '=' only. A '+=' will add onto and increment the actual character value. Therefore, 'a' + 2 = 'c'.